# How to migrate HP Service Manager?

Tags: sql-server, hp, migration

I have built an instance of HP service manager in my Lab environment. I want to migrate the data in my old instance into this new one. It is built on top of a MS SQL-Server DB.

I realize I can probably just interact with the DB and migrate manually, but I wanted to know if there was an easy "GUI" way to extract the data for migration. Has anyone migrated from one HP SM instance to another? How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up-front admission:  I am not running HP service manager, nor have I ever run HP service manager.

I've migrated a lot of vendor applications built on SQL Server, though, and it would generally go like this:

1. Install app on new server.
2. Turn off app services on new host.
3. Turn off SQL on new host.
4. Rename vendor database files (vendorname-back.mdf, vendorname-back.ldf).
5. Turn off app services on old host.
6. Turn off SQL on old host.
7. Copy vendor's .mdf and .ldf to new host.
8. Turn on SQL on new host.
9. Turn on app services on new host.
10. Configure SQL backups on new host.

Sometimes, the hostname is hidden in the database somewhere, but other than that, well.  I personally consider that easier than a wizard.  (That could be because, you know, I've done it somewhere between twenty and a hundred times.  Or, it could be because it's easier.)

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. I am not a DBA, so I didn't even know about the .mdf or .idf... I'll look into those. The other thing I'm a bit concerned about is the older application's schema has altered, and for the new instance, we are going back to a vanilla application. I assume I'll have to do some db field mapping? Either way, I do believe you answered my question.

Comment: Yeah, what I gave you is basically a "brain transplant" of the old instance into the new one.  If you're making changes, well.  Yeah.  You'd have to make them on the new one after the "transplant."